# Streaming file from Hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have 2 Scala applications:
One listens to a HDFS folder for new files (to then push to an API after transforming the data), the other reads data from DB/2 and writes the records as JSON to the HDFS filesystem:

Streaming:

```
/**
 * Read data from HDFS, transform and push to API
 */
object DataMerge extends App {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val conf =  new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("data_merger")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

  val mainStream = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages")

  val messages = mainStream.filter(_.contains("objectUid"))
  messages.print()

  ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/checkpoint")

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

Writing to HDFS:

```
/**
 * Read data from DB2 and write to HDFS
 */
object DB2DataExtractor extends App {
  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

  val conf =  new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("smd_migrator_2")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def createConnection() = {
    Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance()
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://server:1234/database", "user", "password")
  }

  def extractValues(rs: ResultSet): String = {
    write(new Message(rs.getString(1), rs.getLong(2), rs.getLong(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5),))
  }

  val query =
    """SELECT *
      |FROM (
      |   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.insert_time DESC) AS rn,
      |   o.*,
      |   m.*
      |   FROM schema.table o
      |   JOIN schema2.table2 m ON
      |   o.external_id = m.external_id
      |   )
      |WHERE rn BETWEEN ? and ?""".stripMargin

  val data = new JdbcRDD(sc, createConnection, query, lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 2000,
numPartitions = 5, mapRow = extractValues)

  val file = "hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages"
  data.saveAsTextFile(file)
}
```

I start the DataMerge application first to listen to the non-existent directory (so that it can pick up the files once they exist). Once I run the DB2DataExtractor, the data gets written to the HDFS files but the DataMerge app does not output the data to the command line. There is evidence that it's located the new files:

```
15/05/06 13:26:28 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 1 ms
15/05/06 13:26:28 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1430943988000 ms:

15/05/06 13:26:28 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1430943988000 ms
15/05/06 13:26:28 INFO JobGenerator: Checkpointing graph for time 1430943988000 ms
15/05/06 13:26:28 INFO DStreamGraph: Updating checkpoint data for time 1430943988000 ms
15/05/06 13:26:28 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1430943988000 ms.0 from job set of time 1430943988000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1430943988000 ms
-------------------------------------------
```

So far I'm not seeing any output from ready the files. Am I missing something?

I'm running these applications from the command line.

UPDATE

I updated the code to:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val mainStream = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages")
mainStream.print
mainStream.foreachRDD(_.foreach(println))

ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/checkpoint")

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And I can see the files getting recognised:

```
15/05/06 16:32:35 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1430955155000 ms:
hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages/_SUCCESS
hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages/part-00000
hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages/part-00001
hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages/part-00002
hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages/part-00003
hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages/part-00004
```

But seeing the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/spark/messages/_SUCCESS
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
```

Comment: Try printing before the filter. It seems to me that you have nothing in the RDD

Comment: So at the `mainstream` RDD should that have the lines of the files that I can access?